# ERROR FOR INSTALLATION ESXI 7 ON THE VMware Workstation (No network adapters were detected)

Tags: vmware, vsphere, esxi, vmware-workstation, vcenter

I want to use VMware Workstation 15.5.1 to install VMware vSphere ESXi 7 on one VM.

I am using virtual network adaptor which works on my other windows VMs on my vmware workstation( such as AD, and ... ).

I want to install  VMware vSphere ESXi 7, and I am getting bellow error :
“No network adapters were detected. Either no network adapters are physically connected to the system, or a suitable driver could not be located. A third party driver may be required.
Ensure that there is at least one network adapter physically connected to the system before attempting installation. If the problem persists, consult the VMware Knowledge Base.”[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQdgH.jpg)

WHY CANNOT I INSTALL ESXi ON VMWARE WORKSTATION?
HOW CAN I ADD MY NETWORK CARD DRIVER TO MY ISO FILE?
I really appreciate if you have any idea on this problem. I am really stuck!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an issue with the network adapter type being used for some reason. You can change the E1000 adapter to VMXNet3 to resolve the issue.

Alternatively, VMware does provide a pre-built OVA template for situations like this. The 7.0 version is available at the following: [link](https://download3.vmware.com/software/vmw-tools/nested-esxi/Nested_ESXi7.0_Appliance_Template_v1.ova)